# Second Division League popularity

Tags: football

I have a general question regarding soccer (football), in terms of which events are more widely viewed by fans:

Do fans tend to follow second division leagues, or are they more likely to follow domestic cups which might involve second division league clubs?  Do second division leagues tend to have a significant following at all (I realize it will vary from nation to nation - I'm asking for a general assessment.)

Comment: -1 ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site..."](http://sports.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two types of so called "fans" or "supporters". I'm a big fan of my local team (first kind), but I do also like teams from other leagues (a secondary type of supporting). My point is that the first kind of fans will support a team no matter the division. Examples: Argentian teams like Rosario Central and River Plate. Juventus (sent to serie B because of legal issues) in Italy is another example. The thing is popular teams play on the premier league because they have money and support to have the best players (which are paid by the supporters in the end).